# Reserve certain words where User can't use them for username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My Rails app uses usernames to get user's profile path

```
def to_param
  username
end
```

so if a username was `licata`, the profile page would be `http://localhost:3000/licata`.

Clearly, I need to specify certain words like `help` that cannot be used because I have a static page on the app with the route `/help`, so a username like this would create a conflict.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I believe I found the answer. I will post on here in case others have this question. Comment if better way or wrong.

```
validates :username, :exclusion => { :in => %w(foo bar) }
```

where `foo` and `bar` and so on are the words you can't use.